# adding cors to aspx web api 2 hybrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I've added Web API 2 to an existing vb aspx web forms project.  and the routing went into the global asax application_start because I do not have an app_start folder with WebApiConfig as you do in a standard web api project. I downloaded CORS from the nugget package manager add attempted to enable CORS

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application is started

       RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name:="DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        )

    Dim cors = New EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors(cors)

    End Sub
```

however whenever I attempt to run an html page that is making calls to my web api through jquery ajax I receive.

```
  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy
 disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxx/specialdev/api/WSFobOrigin. 
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)
```

So I'm not quite sure what I am missing I attempting adding it to each controller as well.

```
Public Class WSFobOriginController
    Inherits ApiController
    <EnableCors("*", "*", "*")>
    <HttpGet>
    <CustomAuthentication>
    <Authorize(Roles:="WebService")>
    Public Function logon() As IHttpActionResult
        Return Ok("successfully loggon on")
    End Function
```

Here is the ajax call (I tried it with and without the crossDomain: true)

```
  this.logon = function () {
                $('#signin').prop('disabled', true);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://xxxxxxxx.dir.ad.dla.mil/specialdev/api/WSFobOrigin",
                    type: "GET",
                    datatype: "json",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        $('#logonSpinner').show();
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(self.userName() + ":" + self.password()));
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.loggedon(true);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        $('#signin').prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#logonSpinner').hide();
                        $('#logonError').show();
                        self.logOnErrorMessage("Status: " + xhr.status + " Message: " + xhr.statusText)
                    }
                });

            }
```

just noticed one more thing that is a bit odd to me.  when I run the web api locally (through visual studio)  and change my client jquery ajax call to the local url it works.

```
URL Protocol    Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait‎‎  Start‎‎ Request‎‎   Response‎‎  Cache read‎‎    Gap‎‎
http://localhost:52851/api/WSFobOrigin  HTTP    OPTIONS 200     420 B   31 ms   CORS Preflight  0   16  0   15  0   203
```

and

```
URL Protocol    Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait‎‎  Start‎‎ Request‎‎   Response‎‎  Cache read‎‎    Gap‎‎
http://localhost:52851/api/WSFobOrigin  HTTP    GET 200 application/json    447 B   218 ms  XMLHttpRequest  16  15  203 0   0   0
```

but when I change the client to point to the actual server the preflight aborts and the type no longer says OPTIONS it is null

```
URL Protocol    Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait‎‎  Start‎‎ Request‎‎   Response‎‎  Cache read‎‎    Gap‎‎
https://xxxxxxx.dir.ad.dla.mil/specialdev/api/WSFobOrigin   HTTPS       (Aborted)       0 B 47 ms   CORS Preflight  0   47  0   0   0   796
```

some other posts had suggested adding a filter which I tried but that does not seem to work either

Imports System.Web.Http.Filters

```
Public Class AllowCors
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext As HttpActionExecutedContext)
        If actionExecutedContext Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("actionExecutedContext")
        Else
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS")
        End If
        MyBase.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and decorating my controller with allowcors

```
    <AllowCors>
    <EnableCors("*", "*", "*")>
    <HttpGet>
    <CustomAuthentication>
    <Authorize(Roles:="WebService")>
    Public Function logon() As IHttpActionResult
        Return Ok("successfully loggon on")
    End Function
```

but still no luck

```
status: 404
Method:  OPTIONS
Request Headers: Host: xxxxxx.dir.ad.dla.mil
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Connection: keep-alive

Response Headers:  Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 16:53:06 GMT
Content-Length: 1245
```

Comment: can you able to locate `Startup.cs` in your `App_code` in your solutions Structure ? because you mentioned that you are using the web api2

Comment: no, how this went down is we have an existing aspx web forms application and I went into nu get and added in the web api packages after the fact. so I don't get the typical app_start folder like you usually do that has the bundle_config, route_config etc.  Instead the routing and such goes into the global asax under application_start (see the first code block in my post). The other thing that stinks it is a VB app, it has been challenging finding web api examples using vb.

Comment: can you show your webconfig, and also try to enable cors in this way `var context = HttpContext.Current;
  var response = context.Response;
  
  // enable CORS
  response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM *");` in Application_Start

Comment: did you tried to move your enable cors code to top of function above routing ?

Comment: tried moving the enable cors above the routing, also tried adding the add headers to the global asax but it complained there were duplicate headers when I ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure **CORS** support for the Web API at three levels:

1. At the Global level
2. At the Controller level
3. At the Action level

To configure CORS support at the **global level**,
 first install the CORS package (Which you already did)
 and then open WebApiConfig.cs file from App_Start folder.(here you said you dont have that folder)

```
Dim cors = New EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:5901", "*", "*")
config.EnableCors(cors)
```

(As you are not using that method, then we will go to next Level)

**Action Level**

```
    <EnableCors(origins := "*", headers := "*", methods := "*")> 
  <HttpGet>
    <CustomAuthentication>
    <Authorize(Roles:="WebService")>
 Public Function logon() As IHttpActionResult
        Return Ok("successfully loggon on")
    End Function
```

In the above method you need to set parameters to allow all the headers and support all the HTTP methods by setting value to star.

**Controller Level**

```
<EnableCors(origins := "*", headers := "*", methods := "*")> _
Public Class ClassesController
    Inherits ApiController
End Class
```

In this  you need to  set parameters to allow all the headers and support all the HTTP methods by setting value to star. you can exclude one of the actions from CORS support using the [DisableCors] attribute.

So finally Here are the **Attributes of EnableCors**

There are three attributes pass to EnableCors:

1. **Origins**: You can set more than one origins value separated by commas.  If you want any origin to make AJAX request to the API then set origin value to wild card value star.
2. **Request Headers**: The Request header parameter specifies which Request headers are allowed. To allow any header set value to *
3. **HTTP Methods**: The methods parameter specifies which HTTP methods are allowed to access the resource. To allow all methods, use the wildcard value '*'. Otherwise set comma separated method name to allow set of methods to access the resources.

So combining above points in VB you need to Declare as below

```
<EnableCors(origins := "http://localhost:XXX,http://localhost:YYYY", headers := "*", methods := "POST,GET")> _
Public Class ClassesController
    Inherits ApiController
End Class
```

**Update**

Try to Add this Config to your web-config

```
<customHeaders> 
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> 
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" /> 
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" /> 
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" /> 
</customHeaders>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I have set up CORS on all three levels, (as well as adding the custom filter see original post) I have seen some posts suggesting adding the headers to the server.config but I am not allowed to change that config file.  Again everything works fine when I run on local host.  (the client runs on my desktop or another visual studio solution and points to the web api running on local host) the CORS is blocked when it goes to the "real" server.  are there iis 7.5 server settings that could be blocking me?

Comment: @user2744722 try to give this in webconfig `<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>` setting related to the IIS

Comment: so this can go in web.config? not server.config? as I am not allowed to change server.config

Comment: @user2744722 this code bit might be wrong  `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(self.userName() + ":" + self.password()));` here  when you observe your response in network which you posted, its header being changed to 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization` please do check it also.if you want to add the authorization please try to find some process rather than changing the Headers

Comment: @user2744722 yes do it in web-config

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I've asked for the web config to be changed. (I of course am not allowed to do that directly either gotta love working for the government)  I'll let you know.  By the way saw a I hate CORS tshirt on the internet think that would be a wise investment for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107526/discussion-between-webruster-and-user2744722).

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot adding Microsoft.AspNet.Cors. If you use Visual Studio, you can add use this way:

> Tools-> Nuget Package Manager ->Manage Nuget Packages for Solutions

You should find Microsoft.AspNet.Cors and install to api project

Comment: Ok. EnableCors() is maybe wrong,
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
my Web Api config. if you want try this