# api post call works on postman but in mobile app or ajax call it doesn't

Tags: c#, ajax, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, postman

here's the problem
I've got an API with the following address (HTTP post)

```
http://api.novin.solutions/api/member/login
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },

  "data": {
    "username": "mrkeivan",
    "password": "09126101185",
    "uiId": "d960a994-0972-44ba-ae2c-2c3a01e135c1"
  }
```

I need to call this api in another website and a mobile application, to do so I enabled Asp.net APi Cores globally in web config and WebApiConfig.cs

**in WebApiConfig.cs**

```
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

> as well as Web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, name" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

when I call this in postman, it works perfectly
however when I call it through an ajax method or a friend of mine calls it in his mobile app project it returns the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.novin.solutions/api/member/login. Response for preflight
>   has invalid HTTP status code 404 OPTIONS
>   http://api.novin.solutions/api/member/login 404 (Not Found)

I have read many articles in this matter and applied all the suggestions, but nothing fixed my problem :(

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I struggled with something similar a while back. maybe something in my SO question might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137379/adding-cors-to-aspx-web-api-2-hybrid

Comment: I managed to fix it, there were multiple Allow-Origin's in different sections, removed all of them and it worked like like a charm. 
thanx for the response.